# Adding solution items from VisualStudio extension

Tags: c#, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

I am making a test VisualStudio extension that adds new items to solution. I found the way of doing it through trial and error, but I am not satisfied with the complexity of this solution and have some opened questions.. Here is the code:

```
using EnvDTE;
using EnvDTE80;
//..

namespace MyFirstExtension
{
    internal sealed class AddFileToSolution
    {
        public const int CommandId = PackageIds.CmdCreateVaultHelperConfig;
        public static readonly Guid CommandSet = new Guid(PackageGuids.guidVaultHelperVsExtensionPackageCmdSetString);
        private readonly AsyncPackage package;

        private AddFileToSolution(AsyncPackage package, OleMenuCommandService commandService)
        {
            this.package = package ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(package));
            commandService = commandService ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(commandService));

            var menuCommandID = new CommandID(CommandSet, CommandId);
            var menuItem = new MenuCommand(this.Execute, menuCommandID);
            commandService.AddCommand(menuItem);
        }

        public static AddFileToSolution Instance { get; private set; }

        private Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.IAsyncServiceProvider ServiceProvider { get { return this.package; } }

        public static async Task InitializeAsync(AsyncPackage package)
        {
            await ThreadHelper.JoinableTaskFactory.SwitchToMainThreadAsync(package.DisposalToken);

            OleMenuCommandService commandService = await package.GetServiceAsync(typeof(IMenuCommandService)) as OleMenuCommandService;
            Instance = new AddFileToSolution(package, commandService);
        }

        private async void Execute(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await ThreadHelper.JoinableTaskFactory.SwitchToMainThreadAsync();

            string fileFullPath = @"C:\Users\myusr\source\repos\VsExtensionTesting2\0.txt";
            
            var dte = await package.GetServiceAsync(typeof(DTE));
            var dte2 = dte as DTE2;

            var solution2 = (Solution2)dte2.Solution;
            
            // following line throws Exception!
            //solution2.AddFromFile(fileFullPath);

            bool isSolutionItemsFolderExists = IsSolutionItemsFolderExists(solution2);
            if (!isSolutionItemsFolderExists)
            {
                solution2.AddSolutionFolder("Solution Items");
            }

            AddToSolutionItems(solution2, fileFullPath);
        }

        public bool IsSolutionItemsFolderExists(Solution2 solution2)
        {
            foreach (var solutionItemObj in solution2)
            {
                var solutionItem = solutionItemObj as Project;

                string name = solutionItem.Name;
                if (name == "Solution Items")
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }

        public void AddToSolutionItems(Solution2 solution2, string fileFullPath)
        {
            foreach (var solutionItemObj in solution2)
            {
                var solutionItem = solutionItemObj as Project;

                string name = solutionItem.Name;
                if (name == "Solution Items")
                {
                    solutionItem.ProjectItems.AddFromFile(fileFullPath);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here I am using the `Visual Studio 2019` VSIX project template. It uses `AsyncPackage` by default. What I am trying to accomplish is to execute command `Project.AddExistingItem` on `solution` level.

[image]

Questions are:

1. In my solution - why does calling the command `solution2.AddFromFile(fileFullPath);` directly throws exception?

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'The template specified cannot be found. Please check that the full path is correct.'

The file 100% exists in the directory.. Ideally I want to avoid creating `Solution Items` folder myself and let the API handle it..

2. When iterating the solution items/projects I am casting the items to type `Project`, however, during the debugging I can see that the item is also represented by type `System.__ComObject` and `Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.Package.Automation.OAProject` however it's not possible to cast the item to either of the 2 types.. What are these other 2 types (or the correlation between 3 types) and how do I know exactly which type I am supposed to cast the solution items to?
3. What is the use-case for finding the commands executed by VS? I have downloaded the command explorer and captured the `Project.AddExistingItem` command, but how do I actually use this knowledge to execute the command from code? Here is how the command looks like:

[image]

I would be glad to hear some explanations about the questions I mentioned above.. My experience with the VS extension building so far - it's lots of googling and trial and error.. (as opposed to knowing actually what to do :) )

Comment: I cannot get the info about `PackageIds` and `PackageIds`, can you provide them and help me reproduce the issue?

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT CommandId is `0x0101`, `CommandSet` guid value is `"ed464f41-9d8c-4e2d-a43a-45904953bcd7"` if it matters.. You will not find the `PackageIds` class because it's auto generated by custom tool called `VsctGenerator`. It's part of `Extensibility Essentials 2019` VS bundle

Comment: I will test it.